# How U.S. Depreciation works Explain in brief?

Tags: united-states, accounting, depreciation

As per the my Research I came to know few terms about the U.S. Depreciation.

Modified Acclerated Cost Recovery System (MARCS)
Sub Divided into two terms-

General Depreciation System (GDS)  Alternative Depreciation System (ADS)

Generally every one msut use GDS unless you are specifically required by law to use ADS or you elect to use ADS.

Comment: It's not clear how this is a personal finance question (as opposed to accounting).  Perhaps if you feel it is personal finance, you could explain in more detail in the question.  Research about what?  Why are you asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

If a business tool has a limited lifespan, it's value decreases (depreciates) from year to year. The business can capture that loss of value on some things that it couldn't otherwise write off as expenses. A few tools can be either expenses or depreciated, but only one of those can be chosen for that particular object.

This is generally not relevant for individual taxpayers, unless you can show that the item is being used for income-producing purposes.

Comment: But why it mentioned about the depreciation % Tables in the IRS Blog                https://www.irs.gov/publications/p946/ar02.html and how to use them if possible help me out of this ... Thanks

Comment: Start from the other end of the problem. Tell us what you are trying to do, and we may be able to tell you if it is possible and how. Not everything can be depreciated; not everything should be.

Comment: recently I'm started my career with a small corporation which works on U.S. accounting and I'm trying my level best to learn basics about the U.S. accounting............ Thanks (: